# find vs find out

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I know "find" is commonly used with something, and "find out" with information. However, I did see this sentence before:

"I found that....", like, "I found that it costs more than I thought."

My question is: is this correct? And if it is, what the difference between these two:

- I found that it costs more than I thought.
- I found out that it costs more than I thought.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really a question for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). In your context, *found **out*** is effectively being used as an "intensifier" - which could in principle imply that you had to actually *make some effort* to *deliberately* acquire the information, where the unqualified verb ***found*** might simply imply ***became aware*** without particularly seeking [out] the facts of the matter.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I did even know there's another forum.

Comment: If 4 other people here agree with my vote to "migrate" to ELL - or if you simply ask a mod to do it yourself, using the "flag" (for moderator intervention) - I'm sure your question will be well received there, and get a more complete answer than I can provide in a comment. When I cast my vote earlier, I was pretty sure this exact different had already been asked on ELL, but I've just had a good look and I can't find any earlier "duplicate" questions (note that ***out*** would be idiomatically unlikely in ***this*** sentence, which could do with a bit more explanation! :)

Comment: The first sentence seems idiomatically unnatural to me. I would expect it to be written *I* ***have*** *found* that it (always) costs more than I ***think***. In other words, without *out*, I would expect it to be more of a habitual statement than a reference to a single occurrence (which is true of the second sentence).

Comment: Note that [*found out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find%20out) has a specific dictionary definition, distinct from just *find.*

Comment: Thanks Jason! It seems I misunderstood "find that". This is so useful!